# Incompatible packages in meteor (autoform-file and velocity)

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-velocity, meteor-jasmine

This might be a rather general question: How to deal with incompatible packages in meteor?
In my case I'm using the testing suite [velocity](https://github.com/meteor-velocity/velocity) and [jasmine](https://github.com/xolvio/jasmine), which is not compatible with the current version of [autoform-file](https://github.com/yogiben/meteor-autoform-file) package.
My [html-reporter](https://github.com/meteor-velocity/html-reporter) would just continue executing the test without actually getting the result due to the following error:

Errors prevented startup:

```
While selecting package versions:
error: Potentially incompatible change required to top-level dependency: yogiben:autoform-file 0.3.0, was 0.4.2.
Constraints on package "yogiben:autoform-file":

To allow potentially incompatible changes to top-level dependencies, you must pass --allow-incompatible-update on the command line.

Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

I was thinking of downgrading the autoform-file package to 0.3.0 however, I didn't find any information on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to install the package at a specific version using:

```
meteor add yogiben:autoform-file@=0.3.0
```

That worked for me.